# How can I stop 64-bit IE8 from prompting me to install Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, 64-bit

I think the title says it all.

I don't want to switch from IE to Firefox, Chrome, etc.  I don't want to run 32-bit IE.  I'm not trying to install flash into the 64-bit browser.  I don't even want to view flash content.

I only want to stop IE from prompting me whenever I browse a page that *contains* flash content.